# I have this code but it only pastes header and not complete column of data.

Tags: vba, excel

I want the code to paste the entire column if the headers Match. As of now it is only pasting values from Row(1). Thanks a lot. If there are any other questions I will be commenting back quickly. I took out all the Dims and whatnot.

```
Sub sample()

Set sh1 = Sheets("Dec Demand")
Set sh2 = Sheets("List")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Results")
With sh2
    Set rngLookupValues = .Range("J2", .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
Debug.Print rngLookupValues.Address
With sh1
    Set rngHeaders = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
End With
Debug.Print rngHeaders.Address
For Each cValue In rngLookupValues
    lngColumnToCopy = WorksheetFunction.Match(cValue, rngHeaders, 0)
    Debug.Print lngColumnToCopy
    With sh1
        Set rngCellsToCopy = .Range(.Cells(1, lngColumnToCopy), .Cells(Rows.Count, lngColumnToCopy).End(xlUp)) ' HERE i want to have a copy entire column
    End With
    Debug.Print rngCellsToCopy.Address
    With sh3
        lngCurFirstEmptyColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    End With
    Debug.Print lngCurFirstEmptyColumn
    sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCellsToCopy
Next cValue

With sh3.Range("A1")
    If Len(.Value) < 1 Then
        .EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: see my updated answer: you should use `sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngCellsToCopy.Value` instead `sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCellsToCopy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

`sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCellsToCopy`

to

`sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngCellsToCopy.Value`

or

`rngCellsToCopy.Copy sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn)`

(don't know why, but your statement doesn't copy anything, but adding `.Value` fixes the problem)

---

> ' HERE i want to have a copy entire column

If you really need to copy *EntireColumn* (which make your code very slow), follow next steps

**1)** change

```
Set rngCellsToCopy = .Range(.Cells(1, lngColumnToCopy), .Cells(Rows.Count, lngColumnToCopy).End(xlUp))
```

to

```
Set rngCellsToCopy = .Cells(1, lngColumnToCopy).EntireColumn
```

**2)** and then change

```
 sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCellsToCopy
```

to

```
 sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).EntireColumn.Value = rngCellsToCopy.Value
```

or you could use `rngCellsToCopy.Copy sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn)` as well.

---

And one little note: use forgot to add period `.` before `Rows.Count` in the line `Set rngCellsToCopy = .Range(.Cells(1, lngColumnToCopy), .Cells(Rows.Count, lngColumnToCopy).End(xlUp))`

Comment: Maybe I am bias as this was my code, but the reason behind that was it seems much more efficient to copy 10-100k or so rows, (typical amount of data in a lot of excel sheets) then it is to copy 1.6M (Entire Column). Even more so if looping on hundreds of columns.  And For the record I absolutely would NEVER suggest using a Copy paste, ever.

Comment: I agree, but OP says that he would like to copy _Entire column_ (see comment in the line `Set rngCellsToCopy =...` in the Q

Comment: I see your point, But the original code should copy all of the Data from that column, and all the blanks cells will still be blank regardless.

Comment: It's true, and I don't know why OP wants to copy `entire column`

Comment: @user2140261, again `.Value`!! dont know why, but this doesn't copy anything `sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCellsToCopy`, but this works `sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngCellsToCopy.Value`

Comment: Either way +1 for a simple solution to the question asked., Just saw your comment your right!!

Comment: @user2140261, any ideas why? (see my prev comment)

Comment: @user2140261, does this works for you `Range("B1:B3") = Range("A1:A3")` ? It copies nothing for me..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46174/discussion-between-user2140261-and-simoco)

Comment: For me, this all woked. Sorry for delay was offline for an eon.